# Problema con envío de emails desde Laravel 6

Tags: laravel-6

Estoy intentando enviar un correo de notificación mediante la clase Mailable de Laravel 6 y aparentemente todo funciona con normalidad enviando el correo. Mi problema es cuando quiero parsar una variable u objeto a la vista creada con datos específicos que debe llevar dicho correo y que llega vacía o null.

Desde el controlador llamo a la clase y envío al constructor los datos que se mostrarán en la view del mensaje:

```
$msg = Classroom::where('id', $request->classroom_id)->first();

Mail::to('jmrufo@gmail.com')->queue(new MessageReservation($msg));
```

En la clase MessageReservation recojo los datos y los paso a la view

```
class MessageReservation extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $subject = 'Comunicación de Reserva de Aula';
    public $msg;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @param $msg 
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($msg)
    {
        $this->$msg = $msg;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.message_reservation');
    }
}
```

Cuando compruebo el log la cabecera del mensaje sale de forma correcta pero no se imprimen los datos del mensaje porque en la vista no están disponibles y me lanzo el siguiente error

´´´
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Trying to get property 'classname' of non-object (View: C:\laragon\www\reserva-aulas\resources\views\emails\message_reservation.blade.php)
´´´

¿Alguién que le haya pasado algo semejante?.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Problema solucionado.

He modificado la función build() y ya funciona perfectamente. En lugar de llamar a view he utilizado markdown.

´´´
public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.message_reservation',['msg' => $this->msg])->subject('Comunicación de Reserva de Aula');
    }
´´´

Un saludo y gracias